# Prove that $f$ is strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ has the property that for every $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$, $a<b$ there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f$ is continuous at $c$. Given that $f(nx)<f((n+1)x)$ for every $x\in(0,\infty)$ and every $n\in\mathbb{N^*}$, prove that $f$ is strictly increasing.

So far, I have proved that $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{Q_+}$ and $f$ is increasing on $A=\{x\in(0,\infty) \mid  \text{f is continuous at $x$}\}$. Also, I have noticed by the hypotesis that $A$ is dense in $(0,\infty)$, but I can't prove that $f$ is strictly increasing.